# Qt - qstring.h include string error

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I am an admitted noob when it comes to Qt and compiling on linux, so forgive me if this is a simple mistake.

I am attempting to compile a program on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using:
`qmake myprogram.pro && make`

This application uses Qt4. I am getting a strange error that appears to originate in Qt itself.

```
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:48:0,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qiodevice.h:46,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QIODevice:1,
             from src/qt/fervor/quazip/zip.c:22:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:54:20: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
#  include <string>
                   ^
```

I am guessing this is an environment issue rather than an issue with my program. I have poked around the web and some people have suggested c++ build essentials aren't installed. I have verified the Ubuntu build-essentials package is installed.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

So I went into the core qt header file, qstring.h, and found a constant that needed to be defined for my environment (QT_NO_STL). When I define that, I get a new error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:45:0,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:50,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qiodevice.h:46,
             from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QIODevice:1,
             from src/qt/fervor/quazip/zip.c:14:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qiterator.h:50:79: fatal error: new: No such file or directory
# include <new>
```

Comment: So I edited the core qt header file (qstring.h) and replaced "string" with "string.h" and it works. It appears that is done by defining the constant QT_NO_STL. How do I define that compile constant?

Comment: Ok. Figured out how to define QT_NO_STL

Comment: Your Qt installation seems to be broken. Such preprocessor defines should be given to the compiler as command line arguments when it gets invoked in the makefile. Qmake should handle it transparently. You might be mixing Qt versions!

Comment: @KubaOber You were correct. I needed the result of a new qmake -project command. I merged in some of the changes and I am on to a new error :-) If you want to put your comment as an answer I will mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit really belongs to @KubaOber, but in the interest of helping others I am posting the answer that solved my problem.

Turns out that I added a dependency (library) and didn't re-create the .pro file with qmake -project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by just adding the following in the <project>.pro  file:

CONFIG += qt

OR add instead:

CONFIG += qt

QT += svg